# Carrierwave not saving file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have this app to upload a handwritten translation of a video through a little upload form. I then want to attach it to a video.

Here is my model:

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :course, :qa_complete, :qa_id, :subject, :title, 
  :translate_complete, :translator_id, :type_complete, :typer_id, :video_id, :due_date, :translation_handwritten

  validates :video_id, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true #add uniqueness in db too
  mount_uploader :translation_handwritten, TranslationsUploader
end
```

Here is my form view:

```
 =form_tag(:action => 'upload_translation_handwritten', :method => 'post')
   .form-group 
     %label.h4{for: "handwrittenTranslation"} Upload Handwritten Translation
     %input#inputFile{name: 'translation', type: "file"}
     %button.btn.btn-default{type: "submit"} Upload
```

Here is my uploader:

```
class TranslationsUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def default_url
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg pdf png)
  end
end
```

And in my controller I try setting the file:

```
def upload_translation_handwritten
      @video = Video.find_by_video_id(params[:video_id])
      @video.translation_handwritten = params[:translation]
      @video.save!
      ...
  end
```

params[:translation] has the correct info from the form. I've confirmed that. When I try printing @video.translation_handwritten.url though, it just comes up with my default path. Does anyone have any suggestions of what to try? I'm obviously very new to carrierwave...

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with where I set the file to be saved. I should've been sending it to my public/ directory.